# Make inetd pass connection over to an unix-domain socket

Tags: xinetd, inetd

I'm trying to put Postfix behind inetd. The idea is to configure inetd to listen to inet smtp port and make Postfix listen to a unix-domain one.

Is it possible to make inetd pass connection over to a unix-domain socket?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: Want to have tcp wrappers filter connections.

Comment: People still try to use those? Just use the firewall like everyone else.

Comment: I would love to if there was a firewall with host lookup capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a service in inetd with

```
server = /usr/bin/socat
server_args = socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT:/path/to/unix/socket
```

This will connect the service I/O to the socket. See `man socat`.

Comment: socan always stays in between. it does not hand a connection over and leave, right?

Comment: Right. It'll continue to run, as the intermediary between inetd and postfix. So instead of client <-> postfix, you'll have client <-> inetd <-> socat <-> postfix. But it should work fine.

Comment: doesn't inetd leave the chain if configured with nowait?

Comment: Yes, I think so.